# Auto Invoking of a camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a camel route as below, and I wan to invoke this route as soon as my war gets deployed, any Idea how to do this ?

```
<route >
        <from uri="direct-vm:meta-config"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                <constant>GET</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <toD uri="http://....."/>
            <process ref="configInitializer"/>
        </route>
```

Basically, my Idea is to invoke an http endpoint during application start-up, and use the response in the application.

I tried with creating a spring bean @PostConstruct and invoke it via Producer Template, but it throws  "No consumer available endpoint exception".
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might use an extension of `EventNotifierSupport` and listen for `CamelContextStartedEvent` and then call the producer template from there

Comment: @RomanVottner Thanks for the response, Unfortunately out project has multiple camel context ( more than 100 ), so for every Camel context started event, it got notified, Is there something can be done via route policy ?

Comment: As you use Camel on top of Spring, you can also invoke the producer template directly from within [`CamelContextConfiguratin#afterApplicationStart(CamelContext)`](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#SpringBoot-CustomCamelcontextconfiguration). This should be run once when Camel finished setting up all of the registry, services and routes